# Match overall length on regex groups

Tags: regex

I would like to integrate a total length check into the match, unfortunately I only succeed in the length match on the subgroups themselves.

*Requirements*: It should contain an alphanumeric string which contains letters from A-Z as well as numbers from 0-9 as well as 1 slash or 1 space but only in the middle, capturing is not needed.

```
^(?:[A-Z0-9]+(?:(?:-| )[A-Z0-9]+)?)$
```

```
^(?:[A-Z0-9]+(?:(?:-| )[A-Z0-9]+)?){1,11}$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following do what you are after:

```
^(?!.{12})[A-Z0-9]+(?:[- ][A-Z0-9]+)?$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OkZMT3/1). The use of the *hyphen* or space is now optional. Not sure if you want it compulsary, if so:

```
^(?!.{12})[A-Z0-9]+[- ][A-Z0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right (valid string *must* contain at least one character from `A-Z`, `0-9`, `/`,   and must not begins or ends wth `/`,  ), you can try

```
^(?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)(?=.+[\/].+)(?=.+[ ].+).{1,11}$
```

pattern:

```
^              - (anchor) start of the string
(?=.*[A-Z].*)  - contains A-Z somewhere
(?=.*[0-9].*)  - contains 0-9 somewhere
(?=.+[\/].+)   - contains /, but in the middle (not first and not last) 
(?=.+[ ].+)    - contains ' ' (space), but in the middle (not first and not last)
.{1,11}        - from 1 to 11 arbitrary characters
$              - (anchor) end of the string
```